# Open notification in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How can I open a notification in Xamarin. Forms?, I have implemented that receives and shows the notifications even if it is inside the application but I lack the action of the notification, not that to do...

Comment: What do you exactly mean? Could you provide more details? It is pretty much unclear what you're asking so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to fire an action when user clicks your "OK" button on your message which includes notification message. I suggest you to use a custom dialog project like this:
[Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)

When you import that library, u can call a message and give an action method to its interface: (code may not compile, i wrote it randomly)

```
UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(new AlertConfig
            {
                Message = "Your notification message",
                OkText = "OK",
                OnAction = ()=>{/*youraction*/}
            });
```

So when user taps on "OK" your action code will run. Do not forget to use "Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread" method if you make UI changes:)